# Cannot locate the source of mp3 file using <embed src>

Tags: html, embed-tag

I want background music on my page, but i cannot locate it. Ive tried it many times and I am sure the path is correct. Path of the file : C:\Users\matous\Downloads\idklol

```html
</head>

<body>
<div class = 'headings'>randompage.</div>

<embed src=“C:/Users/matous/Downloads/idklol.mp3”>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of music controls window, theres window that says my file does not exist or has been moved.

Comment: use normal quotes `".."` and not curly `“..”`

Comment: Is that path valid on the *client* (browser) side?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the audio file to a path relative to your HTML document?

Given the following:

```
www/index.html
www/assets/idklol.mp3
```

You would set the path in `index.html` as follows:

```
<embed src="./assets/idklol.mp3">
```